# C# Are errors in DataGridView.Datasource assignments handled internally

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have an application that assigns a list of values to a DataGridView.
This is done inside a Try catch block.
Occasionally there is an issue with the with the procedure that produces this list (also in a try catch block) and this causes an error when the assignment is done.
It appears the exception is never caught by the block doing the assignment and the application freezes.

Is the exception handled inside the assignment call so that it is not propagated out to the catch block?

The exception produced as a pop up states 
"The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:
System.IndexOutOfrangeException: Index 1 does not have a value at
System.Windows.Forms.dataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32 rowIndex)
To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event"

The code is basically

```
public void SetupRunners(EventDetails _eventDetails)
    {
        try
        {
            RunnerAssociates.Clear();
            RunnerAssociates = null;

            RunnerAssociates = createRunnerAssociateList(selectedEventDetails);

            runnerAssociatesDataGridView.DataSource = RunnerAssociates;
            runnerAssociatesDataGridView.DataMember = string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            NZRB_Global.Utils.LogException(methodName, ex);
        }
    }

private List<Runner_Associate> createRunnerAssociateList(EventDetails _meetAndRace) //NZRB_Global.MeetAndRace _meetAndRace)
    {
        const string methodName = "createRunnerAssociateList";

        List<Runner_Associate> lra = new List<Runner_Associate>();

        try
        {
            if (null != _meetAndRace)
            {
                _meetAndRace.UpdateAllProfiles();

                foreach (RunnerDetail rd in _meetAndRace.runners.runnerList)
                {
                    Runner_Associate ra = new Runner_Associate();
                    ra.Number = rd.number;
                    ra.RunnerName = rd.name;

                    RunnerProfile profile = rd.GetRunnerProfile();

                    if ((rbJockeyDriver.Checked) || (rbCustom.Checked))
                    {
                        ra.AssociateName = rd.person;
                    }
                    else if (profile != null)
                    {
                        if (rbTrainers.Checked)
                        {
                            ra.AssociateName = profile.trainer;
                        }
                        else if (rbOwners.Checked)
                        {
                            ra.AssociateName = profile.owners;
                        }
                    }
                    lra.Add(ra);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            NZRB_Global.Utils.LogException(methodName, ex); 
        }
        return lra;
    }
```

Comment: To reproduce the issue, could you provide the code that "assigns a list of values to a DataGridView"? And explain where the exception occurred.

Comment: The issue is understanding why the exception is not handled in the Try/Catch block in the code originally posted. I have added the other call to the original post

Comment: set runnerAssociatesDataGridView.DataSource = null and then assign the list to the data source property runnerAssociatesDataGridView.DataSource = RunnerAssociates;.. Remove this data member line..
runnerAssociatesDataGridView.DataMember = string.Empty;